# How to read return value from .EXE

Tags: c#

Can I get some help with getting return value from .EXE in another assembly. I am getting the following error:

> Error 1:Program 'Sample.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point sample.exe.

Customer.cs

```
public int InsertCustomer() {
    return 100;
}
```

Program.cs

```
public static int Main() {
    customer x = new customer ();
    int ID_c = InsertCustomer();
    return ID_c;
}
```

Comment: This code as-is wouldn't compile (you need an instance to call the InsertCustomer() method). But that would give you a different error message from what you are reporting. The signature of the Main() method is correct and you should not get that message. Please double check that the code in your question is the same as what you're trying to run.

Comment: Unless you have a missing bracket maybe, and the compiler got completely lost. Please show the full code.

Comment: Can you post the calling code?

Comment: After removing the 'return ID_C' line, I am able to compile and call the EXE in my application. Thank you all for your responses.